# Undo upvote on a comment in first 60 seconds

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, voting

Why is it only in the first 60 seconds possible to undo an upvote on a comment?

My arguments against it:

1. It takes me even more than 60 seconds to compile tex-code on my
   old machine.
2. If the internet connection is weak I can not undo it
   at all because reloading the page takes longer than 60 seconds.
3. I may later recognize that the upvoted comment was wrong.

So my request is to release these 60 second limit.

Comment: The limit is general for Stack Exchange, not just for us. The old argument is that upvoting comments should not be reversible at all, so be thankful for what we have. Key point is to upvote only once you've checked you want to :-)

Comment: Note that this is identical for all stackexchange.com site, not just this one, and local moderators don't have any direct influence on it. I didn't even know that there is now a 60s limit. Previously it wasn't possible to undue comment votes at all.

Comment: This has been the case since August 2012. See [Can I undo marking a comment as a “great comment”?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/617/5764) As far as I know/understand, the limit for revoking your "great comment" vote is the same for revoking your regular votes for post: 5 minutes. However, it can only be revoked once. My answer to this question would be that you should take some more consideration when voting a comment as great, since it doesn't always seem to be the case...

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment - Key quote "The only use case [for reversing an upvote on a comment] is undoing a mis-click."  See Sparky's comment for a counterargument.  @Werner - the undo limit is indeed 60s for comments according to that link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well my personal opinionated response to that is *So What?* (in a very playful tone). You can even misshoot the click while scrolling the page and it lands on the other comment which is completely wrong but still, so what? No damage is done.

It doesn't measure anything and it certainly doesn't effect anything. If it seems correct temporarily then upvote it and you would be wrong with someone else with the same preconception. Is it a bad thing? No. Is it something that will bother you for a long time? I hope not.